# Alternative for optmatch in R

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

The library optmatch that is used with MatchIt library is not compatible with R 4.1.2 and seems to be discontinued. Any one aware of an alternative without having to downgrade to an old verion? I'm trying to run full matching using a probit regression model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optmatch` was taken down recently for some CRAN-related reasons that have nothing to do with its performance or compatibility with R version 4.1.2. You can definitely install the most recent archived version of `optmatch` and it will work fine with the current version of R. You can also install it from the maintainer's GitHub page using `remotes::install_github("markmfredrickson/optmatch")`.

That said, if for some reason you don't want to do this, there are other matching methods that have similar performance to full matching, the most straightforward of which is subclassification (i.e., `method = "subclass"`). If you enter a high number of subclasses, the result may be similar to the full matching result in composition and performance. `matchit()` guarantees each subclass has at least one treated and one control unit. You can also try propensity score weighting using the `WeightIt` package. Full matching is a coarsened (robust) form of propensity score weighting, but there are weighting methods that often have superior performance and can be used with ease.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked! Also installed an archived version of RItools and its dependencies. Thanks a lot for the second suggestion too!

Answer (score -1):

Install an older version from the repository this way to keep using it:

```
devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/optmatch/optmatch_0.9-17.tar.gz")
```

Comment: He said  "Any one aware of an alternative without having to downgrade to an old version?", so why do you suggest to downgrade it?